# Transform Hierarchy Tree into Parent/Child Table with Excel Formulas

Tags: excel-formula, parent-child, hierarchy

I am trying to transform a hierarchy with 5 Levels into a Parent/Child table with 2 columns.

I need to do this with Excel formulas, not VBA script. Can I do this with `Index` and `Match` functions?

The Parent/Child Table should be dynamic and update automatically if Hierarchy changes.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **H I E R A R C H Y** |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Universe |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | North America |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  | USA |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  | California |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  | San Francisco |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | Los Angeles |
| 8 |  |  |  | Montana |  |
| 9 |  |  | Mexico |  |  |
| 10 |  |  | Canada |  |  |
| 11 |  | Europe |  |  |  |
| 12 |  |  | Italy |  |  |
| 13 |  |  | Spain |  |  |
|  |  |  | France |  |  |

I was able to populate the Children with the array formula below, i.e. North America in B2:

```
{=INDEX(A3:E3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A3:E3),0))}
```

However I am looking for a formula to populate the Parents.

Expected Parent / Child Table:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Parent** | **Child** |
| 2 | Universe | North America |
| 3 | North America | USA |
| 4 | USA | California |
| 5 | California | San Francisco |
| 6 | California | Los Angeles |
| 7 | USA | Montana |
| 8 | North America | Mexico |
| 9 | North America | Canada |
| 10 | Universe | Europe |
| 11 | Europe | Italy |
| 12 | Europe | Spain |
| 13 | Europe | France |

Answer (score 1):

I think the `INDEX` and `MATCH` method that works for the children will not work for the parents because:

- Your data structure implies that there is a single piece of information per row therefore `{=INDEX(A3:E3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A3:E3),0))}` always works for a child value
- But, the parent for that child value is the value in the *prior* column and an *unknown number of rows above* the row of the child. So, because the `INDEX`/`MATCH` approach does not return the location of the child in order that we can figure out the *prior* column that needs to be identified and addressed etc.

We can think about the parent value being in row of the column with the maximum index of a non-blank values up to and including that row.

E.g. for Spain the range to check for the parent is:

[image]

E.g. for Los Angeles the range to check for the parent is:

[image]

So to establish the correct range to check for the parent value for a child, you need to offset by -1 column and from the min row (2) to the max row (the row of the child).

To do this we need to get:

1. The row/ column coordinates of the children (and therefore we can also know the child value)
2. The min and max row of the prior column (the parent must exist in a non-blank value in that column)
3. Resolve values via an `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` approach against row/ column indices

So it will end up like this:

[image]

Where:

### Child addresses

- C_row: `=ROW(A2:E2)` is simply the row of the hierarchy
- C_col: `=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(A2:E2)),COLUMN(A2:E2))` is a non-array formula version of your formula that returns the index of the non-blank cell instead of the value itself
- C_add: `=ADDRESS(G2,H2)` is the address of the child value per `C_row` and `C_col` above

### Parent addresses

- P_col: `=H2-1` is the *prior* column to the child column (`C_col`); which we know has the parent value
- P_add_min: `=IF(J2>0,ADDRESS(2,J2),"zzz")` is the address of the minimum row of the range containing the parent, with a condition to identify the root of the hierarchy (i.e. `Universe` has no parent)
- P_add_max: `=IF(J2>0,ADDRESS(G2,J2),"zzz")` is the address of the maximum row of the range containing the parent, with the same condition as `P_add_min` re root of the hierarchy
- P_row: `=IF(J2>0,AGGREGATE(14,4,(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(K2&":"&L2)))*ROW(INDIRECT(K2&":"&L2))),1),"zzz")` says where the child is not the root of the hierarchy, get the `LARGE`st index of a non-blank value in the *prior* column to the child between the min and max rows established above

### Expected output

- Parent: `=IF(J2>0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(M2,J2)),"zzz")` gets the value at the address given by `P_row` and `P_col`
- Child: `=INDIRECT(I2)` gets the value at the address given by `C_add`

### Extensibility

The method above accounts for a hierarchy of arbitrary number of components where the maximum depth of the hierarchy is 5 (e.g. leaves in column `E`).

If you want to have arbitrary depth as well then you need to separate the helper columns and output columns into a different sheet e.g.

- C_row: `=ROW(Sheet1!2:2)`
- C_col: `=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!2:2)),COLUMN(Sheet1!2:2))`
- C_add: `=ADDRESS(A2,B2,1,1,"Sheet1")`
- P_col: `=B2-1`
- P_add_min: `=IF(D2>0,ADDRESS(2,D2),"zzz")`
- P_add_max: `=IF(D2>0,ADDRESS(A2,D2),"zzz")`
- P_row: `=IF(D2>0,AGGREGATE(14,4,(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&E2&":"&F2)))*ROW(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&E2&":"&F2))),1),"zzz")`
- Parent: `=IF(D2>0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(G2,D2,1,1,"Sheet1")),"zzz")`
- Child: `=INDIRECT(C2)`

And you can go ahead and rename `zzz` just as `""` to tidy things up.

HTH